# How to sort an arraylist of multiple strings based on the highest value of the last column?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have printed data from a text file of type double and converting it into an array of double that looks like this

```
[-2.0, -2.0, -2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.39E-04 
-2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 2.0, 0.020446 
0.0, -2.0, 2.0, 2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.032339 
2.0, -2.0, -2.0, 2.0, 2.0, -2.0, 2.0, 0.026673 
0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.094135 
0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.045922 
-2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.117043 
-2.0, -2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, -2.0, 0.425709 
-2.0, -2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.156286]
```

The last column is the score of each row that calculated based on specific equation. My question is how can I sort this arraylist based on the highest value of the last column? 
The output of the sorted array should be like this

```
-2.0, -2.0, -2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.39E-04 
-2.0, -2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, -2.0, 0.425709 
-2.0, -2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.156286 
-2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.117043 
0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.094135 
0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.045922 
0.0, -2.0, 2.0, 2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.032339 
2.0, -2.0, -2.0, 2.0, 2.0, -2.0, 2.0, 0.026673 
-2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 2.0, 0.020446
```

the code I tried so far

```
ArrayList<String> a2 = new ArrayList<String>();
               File file7 = new File("kk.txt");
                  BufferedWriter output7 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file7));
                  output7.write(array+"");
                  output7.close();
                  Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader("kk.txt"));
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                String line1 = s.nextLine();
                //store this line to string [] here
               line1 = line1.replaceAll("\\[", "");
               line1 = line1.replaceAll("\\]", "");
               line1= line1.replaceAll("\\;,","\r\n"+"");
               line1= line1.replaceAll("\\;","\r\n"+"");
                a2.add(line1);

            }
           Collections.sort(a2,Collections.reverseOrder());
              System.out.println("Sorted List : " + a2);
```

but the code return the array without sorting. Any help is appreciated

Comment: You should first split each row into separate `double` values and then use a custom `Comparator` for sorting.

Comment: can you use a standard file format? (eg. csv rfc4180)

Comment: thanks @PavelSmirnov, could you show me by the code because im still beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one of possible solutions for your problem:

```java
List<String> a2 = ...; //your list
        Collections.sort(a2, 
                    Collections.reverseOrder((s1, s2) -> {
                        String[] d1 = s1.split(",");
                        String[] d2 = s2.split(",");
                        return Double.compare(Double.parseDouble(d1[d1.length-1]), 
                                              Double.parseDouble(d2[d2.length-1]));
                    }));

a2.forEach(System.out::println);
```

For Java 1.7:

```java
Collections.sort(a2, 
                    Collections.reverseOrder(new Comparator<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                            String[] d1 = s1.split(",");
                            String[] d2 = s2.split(",");
                            return Double.compare(Double.parseDouble(d1[d1.length-1]), 
                                                  Double.parseDouble(d2[d2.length-1]));
                        }
                    }));
```

Output:

```
-2.0, -2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, -2.0, 0.425709
-2.0, -2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.156286
-2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.117043
0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.094135
0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.045922
0.0, -2.0, 2.0, 2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.032339
2.0, -2.0, -2.0, 2.0, 2.0, -2.0, 2.0, 0.026673
-2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 2.0, 0.020446
-2.0, -2.0, -2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.39E-04
```

*NOTE*: `1.39E-04` is actually a [Scientific Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) and its value is `0.000139`. That's why it appears to be at the end of the list.

Comment: when I add this code inside my code it does not work? could you show why?

Comment: What exactly "does not work"? Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: I use java version 1.7

Comment: @user11801243, this code uses lambda expressions which were introduced in Java 8 only. Updated the answer and added code compatible with Java 7.

Comment: the code so nice just one step and the answer will be accepted. how to remove parentheses to make the code working well

Comment: @user11801243, which parentheses? You mean square brackets?

Comment: @user11801243, as long as I can see you're already removing them from the Strings you add to the list: `line1 = line1.replaceAll("\\[", "");
`. Where else do you want to remove them?

Comment: but when do this  a2.add(line1); the square brackets  appear again which make a problem in sorting

Comment: You'd have `NumberFormatException` if there was a bracket. How do you know it's there? If you're looking at the output of `System.out.println("Sorted List : " + a2);` then it's the implementation of `ArrayList.toString()` method which adds the brackets, just for the sake of printing it to the console.

Comment: yes I observe them from the printing statement and because still getting the array not sorted, I thought that the brackets are the problem.. sorry for that

Comment: Create a custom array of Strings and try to run the code again. I've tested the sorting and it works well.

Comment: also printing a2.add(line1); has brackets. and this the input for the sorting code

Comment: You should create a new question regarding this problem and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), there's obviously an error somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Comparator<String> cmp = (o1, o2) -> {
        final Double a1Double = Double.valueOf(o1.substring(o1.lastIndexOf(" ")));
        final Double a2Double = Double.valueOf(o2.substring(o2.lastIndexOf(" ")));
        return a1Double < a2Double ? 0 : -1;

    };
```